# Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app -> NOT WORKING

Tags: android

I know there are some topics about this and some solution but it is not working for me...

I had try [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a?answertab=active#tab-top) the most voted, there is no error but no email too :(

Can you help me with the code?

i have a button and when i click it i want the device to send the email. I am running the software on my android device, not on the emulator (HTC One S - Android 4.0.4 Stock)

I will appreciate your help!
Thanks!

Comment: See below link for complete example of send mail using Java API. [Android – Send Email Via GMail (Actually Via SMTP)](http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2012/05/android-send-email-via-gmail-actually.html)

Comment: If you would be so kind to explain *why* it doesn't work it will be much *much* easier for anyone to help you. Do you get any exception, compile time errors, runtime errors, does the app just crash? There's a few try-catch with empty catch handlers in the top voted answer on that page, have you tried adding a handler that displays an exception if it occurs?

Comment: :(( not working the same problem

Comment: **it is not sending the email :(**

Comment: @ibancioiu post full error logcat.

Comment: there is no error, just warning..
11-03 10:53:06.711: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(14658): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection


11-03 10:53:06.711: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(14658): InputConnection = com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection@40e5e6f8, active client = false

Comment: Well, then I can't help you. If you want more tips on how to explain your problems (other than "It won't work") please read [Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)

Comment: ok, can you create a project in eclipse an run it? If it works just attach it and i will try id, i don't know what to do, because it isn't working :(

Comment: it dosen't crush it dosen't do anything, not freezeing  :(, this is the problem (sorry for my english)

Comment: That's why I asked you to catch the exceptions in the catch handlers. If the application doesn't throw any exceptions, it will be very difficult to help from the description "it doesn't do anything".

Comment: i don't understand what you need, but i had try to add finish(); in try{...} and in works (the program is closing), the same with catch(...){....}

EDIT:

can you create a project in eclipse an run it and send it on ibancioiu@fedoraproject.org to compare the code... i don't know what is wrong with the code, just changed the username and password in MailSenderActivity.java :|

Comment: You can remove the try catch handlers altogether, at least then the application will crash. In order for you to know what the problem is you need to catch the errors and *display* them! An empty catch handler will not display an error if it occurs, so you won't know what went wrong. Please read a tutorial on how exception handling works. And **no**, I won't create a project and do it for you.

Comment: See here to [Send mail from Android application without using default/built-in application](http://v4all123.blogspot.in/2013/10/send-mail-from-android-application.html)